# Sitecore JSS deploy issue: Unexpected response from import status service

Tags: jss

While trying to import a JSS app to my sitecore instance, I'm getting the below error: [image: re]
No errors getting logged in Sitecore log file. How to debug further?

Comment: Are you sure you are giving right Tenant name?

Comment: It appears as though you're using some custom tooling / scripts to deploy, i.e. `npx babel-node scripts/jss-package`. You may want to start with that tooling. Also, the screenshot appears to be cropped so it's difficult to see the actual message. That said, there appears to be a `Not Found` message that would likely indicate a 404 response is being sent for the requested import service URL. Be sure to check your JSS deployment configuration settings.